# How can I change the values of Python variables using bash?

Tags: python, bash

I am writing a Bash script which automates an installation process on Linux. At one point, I need to go inside a Python file which is used as a configuration file for the application being installed and change the values of two specific variables to new values. In other words, suppose I have a .py file which contains (note: `"apple"` and `"orange"` may change):

```
# Some code here
a = "apple"
b = "orange"
# Rest of file
```

And I always need to change those values to *specifically* `"banana"` and `"pear"`:

```
# Some code here
a = "banana"
b = "pear"
# Rest of file
```

How can I automate this change using Bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As unwind says, if you can modify the python script, get it to accept the values as parameters.  However, sometimes you can't do that, because the script is provided by some external package. So sed's in-place search and replace looks like this:

```
sed -i 's/a = "apple"/a = "banana"/' filename
```

Using bash variables, you have to use "" for sed, otherwise the shell won't expand any variables. This means you have to escape the literal " marks, making it less clear to read:

```
export TESTVAR="banana"
sed -i "s/a = \"apple\"/a = \"$TESTVAR\"/" filename
```

To swap them no matter what was in the original:

```
sed -i 's/a = ".*"/a = "banana"/' filename
```

Comment: This is closer to what I want than the other answer. But suppose the values might not always be `"apple"` and `"banana"`. What do I do in that case?

Comment: Do you have the values in bash variables? If not, where are they kept?

Comment: I suppose they could be placed into bash variables. Otherwise, I'm just trying to ensure those two variables in the Python file are always set specifically to `"banana"` and `"pear"`, regardless of whatever they were set to in the original version of the file.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then: sed -i 's/a = ".*"/a = "banana"/' foo

Answer (score 7):

Probably by using `sed` on the script's source, but that's going to be pretty brittle and generally horrible.

The proper solution is probably to make the script accept the required values as command-line arguments, instead.

Comment: *"The proper solution is probably to make the script accept the required values as command-line arguments..."* This would not work for me. The values I need to change are meant to be hardcoded in the Python script, which gives the larger application it is part of access to a database set up earlier in the process.

Comment: @WarriorIng64 You can't have default values in there, and have optional arguments?

Comment: @Marcin No. The Python script is not something which is called by either the user or Bash. It's actually used as a configuration file in this case for the application being installed.

Comment: @WarriorIng64 If you have configuration which needs to change dynamically, then you probably should store it in some kind of database.

Comment: @WarriorIng64 Or alternatively, move some of this configuration into environment variables.

Comment: @Marcin I can't, because it's not my application. I just want to automate the installation process, not modify the way the application works.

Comment: @WarriorIng64 In that case, your question boils down to "how do I write a file". And that's really far too broad.

Answer (score 1):

Django uses Python files as configuration too, and there are various way to handle this kind of problem. A very common one is to have different sets of configuration files for the different environnements and use a symlink to the appropriate one. A possibly better solution is to have your configuration file read the values from the environnement (using `os.environ`, possibly with a sane default value) - then you only have to setup the environnement locally.